# How to avoid making functions for many variables in javasccript?

Tags: javascript, function

I have run in a more or less big problems while writing a script for a small website.

What am I trying to make is a stats sheet creator, for now only the stats calculation.

Lets say

```
var statEndurance = 4;
var statStrength = 4;
var statAgility = 4;
var statMagic = 4;
var statMind = 4;
var statCharisma = 4;

var bonusPoints = 20;
```

Declared variables.
You can only have 1 to 10 on each stat (Not a problem) The difficulty is the calculating of custom points!

```
Score ____________ Points Cost
_ 1 __________________-3
_ 2 __________________-2
_ 3 __________________-1
_ 4 __________________ 0
_ 5 __________________ 1
_ 6 __________________ 3
_ 7 __________________ 5
_ 8 __________________ 8
_ 9 __________________11
_10 _________________ 15
```

If you have 5 on one stat you need 3 points to increase it on 6

What I have tired.

```
function pointCosts(args) {

  switch (args) {
    case 1:
      points = points + 3;

      displayStats();
      break;
    case 2:
      points = points + 2;

      displayStats();
      break;
    case 3:
      points = points + 1;

      displayStats();
      break;
    case 4:
      points = points + 1;

      displayStats();
      break;
    case 5:
      points = points - 1;

      displayStats();
      break;
    case 6:
      points = points - 3;

      displayStats();
      break;
    case 7:
      points = points - 5;

      displayStats();
      break;
    case 8:
      points = points - 8;

      displayStats();
      break;
    case 9:
      points = points - 11;

      displayStats();
      break;
    case 10:
      points = points - 15;

      displayStats();
      break;
  }

};
```

If I increase "Mind" to 5 the bonus points will decrease to 19
but if I do change Mind back to 4 again the points will not change, see above code.

But for checking every stat I use

```
var enoughpoints = true;

function pluscheckpoints(args) {

  if (args == 5 && points < 1) {
    enoughpoints = false;
  }
  if (args = 6 && points < 3) {
    enoughpoints = false;
  }
  if (args = 7 && points < 5) {
    enoughpoints = false;
  }
  if (args = 8 && points < 8) {
    enoughpoints = false;
  }
  if (args = 9 && points < 11) {
    enoughpoints = false;
  }
  if (args = 10 && points < 15) {
    enoughpoints = false;
  }

}
```

And

```
function plusEND() {
  pluscheckpoints(plusEND);
  if (END <= 9) {
    if (enoughpoints = true) {
      END++;
      pointCosts(END);
      displayStats();
      minusgrayitout();
    }
  }
  document.getElementById('minusEND').removeAttribute("onclick");


}

function minusEND() {
  if (END >= 2) {
    if (enoughpoints = true) {
      END--;
      pointCosts(END);
      displayStats();
      plusgrayitout();
    }
  }
  document.getElementById('plusEND').removeAttribute("onclick");
}


function plusSTR() {
  if (STR <= 9) {
    if (enoughpoints = true) {
      STR++;
      pointCosts(STR);
      displayStats();
    }
  }



}

function minusSTR() {
  if (STR >= 2) {
    if (enoughpoints = true) {
      STR--;
      pointCosts(STR);
      displayStats();
    }
  }

}

function plusAGI() {
  if (AGI <= 9) {
    if (enoughpoints = true) {
      AGI++;
      pointCosts(AGI);
      displayStats();
    }
  }

}

function minusAGI() {
  if (AGI >= 2) {
    if (enoughpoints = true) {
      AGI--;
      pointCosts(AGI);
      displayStats();
    }
  }

}

function plusMAG() {
  if (MAG <= 9) {
    if (enoughpoints = true) {
      MAG++;
      pointCosts(MAG);
      displayStats();
    }
  }

}

function minusMAG() {
  if (MAG >= 2) {
    if (enoughpoints = true) {
      MAG--;
      pointCosts(MAG);
      displayStats();
    }
  }

}

function plusMND() {
  if (MND <= 9) {
    if (enoughpoints = true) {
      MND++;
      pointCosts(MND);
      displayStats();
    }
  }

}

function minusMND() {
  if (MND >= 2) {
    if (enoughpoints = true) {
      MND--;
      pointCosts(MND);
      displayStats();
    }
  }

}

function plusCHA() {
  if (CHA <= 9) {
    if (enoughpoints = true) {
      CHA++;
      pointCosts(CHA);
      displayStats();
    }

  }

}

function minusCHA() {
  if (CHA >= 2) {
    if (enoughpoints = true) {
      CHA--;

      pointCosts(CHA);
      displayStats();
    }

  }

}
```

Do you have a way to avoid is many functions? I do dislike jquery, so if it is the only possible way to avoid this mess and make things simpler please tell me.

Comment: Why are some point costs negative?

Comment: Sidenote: you seem to assign in the if statement. Is that intentionally?

Comment: If you find that your code is overly repetitive, make a function that does the repetitive task, and use parameters for the things that change.

Comment: The negative costs are to get more bonus points.
"assign in the if statement" Where?

Comment: `if (enoughpoints = true)` assigns, `if (enoughpoints == true)` compares, you seem to make this mistake a lot.

Comment: There are many things going not in an ideal way. The code reads very procedural, with lot of global variables and side effects. Also, you should wonder if you actually need all these variable or if you couldn't group them in an array or object. On that front, the question reads borderline off topic and may be more fit on code review,

Comment: 4castle, if I use parameters. Lets say End is a var. we push end through a function, but how do we assign the result to the var again? and there could be 1000 different vars that need be done.

Comment: @Clearoi Put the variable in an object, and then use bracket notation on a string to dynamically mutate the value. `obj[key] = value;`

Answer (score 0):

Just a laundry list of stuff that might help:

-An easy solution to clean up the variables is to use an object literal. It's just a JSON-formatted object that's a variable.

```
// Object literal
var stats = {
  "Endurance" : 4,
  "Strength" : 4,
  "Agility" : 4,
  "Magic" : 4,
  "Mind" : 4,
  "Charisma" : 4,
  "BonusPoints" : 20
};

// Calling the object
stats.Endurance; // 4
```

You can clean up all the variables with that.

-A more advanced option might be using a constructor to create the each instance of `stat`. ES5 version:

```
// Creation of `stat` object requires a model name passed into it
function stat( endurance, strength, agility, magic, mind, points, bonus ) {
  this.endurance = endurance;
  this.strength = strength;
  this.agility = agility;
  this.magic = magic;
  this.charisma = charisma;

  // Flattens the whole thing out - but you could do whatever here
  this.toString = function () {
    return this.endurance;
  }
}

// Create list of stats to create
var newStatObject = new stat(4,4,4,4,4,4,0,20);
```

-Your `switch` statement is only one function, so pretty hard to reduce that any further. I don't see any jQuery so you are good there.

-The series of functions you have listed last would be better served with the single function + `switch` statement pattern you used above (taking liberties to not rewrite everything, but you should get the idea):

```
function MAGCheck(magVar) {
  switch {
   case 1:
    if (magVar >= 2) {
      displayStats();
    }
   break;
   case 2:
    if (magVar <= 9) {
      MND++;
      pointCosts(MND);
      displayStats();
    }
   break;
  }
 }
```

-Also, note in your list of functions at the end, your comparisons won't work correctly because you are using assignment (`=`) instead of comparison operators (`==` | `===`):

```
function minusEND() {
  if (END >= 2) {
    if (enoughpoints === true) {
      END--;
      pointCosts(END);
      displayStats();
      plusgrayitout();
    }
  }
  document.getElementById('plusEND').removeAttribute("onclick");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I have done it
t

```
   var stats = {
  "Endurance": 4,
  "Strength": 4,
  "Agility": 4,
  "Magic": 4,
  "Mind": 4,
  "Charisma": 4,
  "BonusPoints": 20
};

var formular = {
  "f1": +3,
  "f2": +2,
  "f3": +1,
  "f4": -0,
  "f5": -1,
  "f6": -3,
  "f7": -5,
  "f8": -8,
  "f9": -11,
  "f10": -15
};

var submitSwitch = false;


function checkBonusPointsFromBeingInvalid() {
  if (stats.bonusPoints <= 0) {
    submitSwitch = false;
  }
}

function displayStats() {
  document.getElementById("endurance").value = stats.Endurance;
  document.getElementById("strength").value = stats.Strength;
  document.getElementById("agilility").value = stats.Agility;
  document.getElementById("magic").value = stats.Magic;
  document.getElementById("mind").value = stats.Mnd;
  document.getElementById("charisma").value = stats.Charisma;
  document.getElementById("points").innerHTML = "Bonus Points " + stats.BonusPoints;
  console.log("Displayed Stats!");
}

function bonusPointsCosts(args) {

  switch (args) {
    case 1:
      if (args === 1) {
        bonusPointsToReduce = bonusPointsToReduce + formular.f1;
      }
      break;
    case 2:
      if (args === 2) {
        stats.BonusPoints = 20;
        stats.BonusPoints = stats.BonusPoints + formular.f2;
      }
      break;
    case 3:
      if (args === 3) {
        stats.BonusPoints = 20;
        stats.BonusPoints = stats.BonusPoints + formular.f3;
      }
      break;
    case 4:
      if (args === 4) {
        stats.BonusPoints = 20;
        stats.BonusPoints = stats.BonusPoints + formular.f4;
      }
      break;
    case 5:
      if (args === 5) {
        stats.BonusPoints = 20;
        stats.BonusPoints = stats.BonusPoints + formular.f5;
      }
      break;
    case 6:
      if (args === 6) {
        stats.BonusPoints = 20;
        stats.BonusPoints = stats.BonusPoints + formular.f6;
      }
      break;
    case 7:
      if (args === 7) {
        stats.BonusPoints = 20;
        stats.BonusPoints = stats.BonusPoints + formular.f7;
      }
      break;
    case 8:
      if (args === 8) {
        stats.BonusPoints = 20;
        stats.BonusPoints = stats.BonusPoints + formular.f8;
      }
      break;
    case 9:
      if (args === 9) {
        stats.BonusPoints = 20;
        stats.BonusPoints = stats.BonusPoints + formular.f9;
      }
      break;
    case 10:
      if (args === 10) {
        stats.BonusPoints = 20;
        stats.BonusPoints = stats.BonusPoints + formular.f10;
      }
      break;
  }
}
////////////TEST//////////////////////////////////////
stats.Endurance = 4;
bonusPointsCosts(stats.Endurance);
console.log("Endurance: " +stats.Endurance + "\n" + "Bonus Points: " + stats.BonusPoints + "\n");
stats.Endurance = 5;
bonusPointsCosts(stats.Endurance);
console.log("Endurance: " + stats.Endurance + "\n" + "Bonus Points: " + stats.BonusPoints + "\n");
stats.Endurance = 6;
bonusPointsCosts(stats.Endurance);
console.log("Endurance: " + stats.Endurance + "\n" + "Bonus Points: " + stats.BonusPoints + "\n");
stats.Endurance = 7;
bonusPointsCosts(stats.Endurance);
console.log("Endurance: " + stats.Endurance + "\n" + "Bonus Points: " + stats.BonusPoints + "\n");
stats.Endurance = 6;
bonusPointsCosts(stats.Endurance);
console.log("Endurance: " + stats.Endurance + "\n" + "Bonus Points: " + stats.BonusPoints + "\n");
stats.Endurance = 5;
bonusPointsCosts(stats.Endurance);
console.log("Endurance: " + stats.Endurance + "\n" + "Bonus Points: " + stats.BonusPoints + "\n");
stats.Endurance = 4;
bonusPointsCosts(stats.Endurance);
console.log("Endurance: " + stats.Endurance + "\n" + "Bonus Points: " + stats.BonusPoints + "\n");
stats.Endurance = 3;
bonusPointsCosts(stats.Endurance);
console.log("Endurance: " + stats.Endurance + "\n" + "Bonus Points: " + stats.BonusPoints + "\n");
```

My problem is to run bonusPointsCosts throught every stat